# The robot is sometimes overlapped by the edge of land

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

On very short pages, such as [search](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/search) and maybe others, the robot is overlapped by the edge of landmass, which looks strange. (Firefox 46)

[image: screen]

Comment: Same in Iceweasel 38.2.1.

Answer (score 2):

Pushing a fix for this now. It should be live soon. Thanks again!

Comment: Now IMO it looks like it's too close to the top of the page instead. Compare the two images at the bottom of http://meta.worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/2916/29 with how it looks now.

Comment: Gonna do some tweaking, and also make it so that it doesn't cut off if your monitor isn't very wide.